# Where does Visual Studio 2017 store the Recent Projects listed on the Start tab?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to back up these items before reinstalling VS. Where can I find them? I found an answer saying that this data is stored in the registry, but it doesn't seem to be the case for VS17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS2017 no longer uses the actual Windows registry, and uses a registry file stored at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<random-characters>\privateregistry.bin`.

You can load it as a hive in the registry editor if you want to look into it to check for the start page contents. Otherwise simply try copying and restoring that file in your new installation.

Answer (score 9):

If you use VS 2022 then have a look into:

**C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_some_random_ id\ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml**

It' a json file with some weird xml at the start and end.

Regards

Comment: VS 2019 also uses this file.

Answer (score 6):

To complete @ray-koopa's answer:

To change values in the private registry hive by hand, you can use `regedit.exe` to load a private hive. You need to select the `HKEY_USERS` node, and click the `File > Load Hive…` menu. You select the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_<id>\privateregistry.bin`  file, give a name to the hive (I entered `VS2017PrivateRegistry`) and now you can see the `15.0_<id>_Config` key populated as usual

Note: use `File > Unload Hive` when done

[image: Clear MRU list in Visual Studio 2017]

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f636ee47-1eb7-45ed-ae2a-674cbabb8b2c/clear-mru-list-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: I cannot find the start page's recent items list in this hive.
....\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7393ba1a

Answer (score 1):

If you use the key name as **VS2017PrivateRegistry** the location where recent file list will be:-
VS2017PrivateRegistry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_\ApplicationPrivateSettings_metadata\baselines\CodeContainers\Offline